# How do I know (on the server side) if someone came to it from an iframe or directly? See inside

Tags: php, javascript, html, referrer

Say, I have a site with URL site.com . How do I know if a referrer gets my URL from an iframe, like this:
    `<iframe src="http://site.com"></iframe>` OR a referrer CLICKS (!!) this link at some site, where link is a usual a-tag: `<a href="http://site.com">go to site</a>` ?

I wanna tell those two apart on my server-side. Maybe, there is a way to do that via JS? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done in javascript, but not on the server-side directly. You can, however, pass this information to the server by redirecting in one of the two cases with a simple javascript:

```
if (window.self === window.top) {
  // you're not in an iframe
} else {
  // in an iframe (or other frames), act accordingly
}
```

Optionally, if you just want to prevent your site from being viewed in an iframe, you can do this by sending an [X-Frame-Options header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header).

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is client side only (unless you are using Node.js), so there is no way to tell on the server side whether something is being referenced from an iframe or a normal hyperlink.

What is your reason for wanting to do this?  It seems as though you are going to have to find another way around your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to prevent your site from being displayed in an iframe, one of the best ways you can do this is with a frame-breaking script. (Note that the request/response will still occur with your webserver).

Include the following in the `<head>` of any document you wish not to be "framed".

```
<style id="antiClickjack">body{display:none !important;}</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
   if (self === top) {
       var antiClickjack = document.getElementById("antiClickjack");
       antiClickjack.parentNode.removeChild(antiClickjack);
   } else {
       top.location = self.location;
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Here's a link to a `owasp.org` document about this approach: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet#Best-for-now_Legacy_Browser_Frame_Breaking_Script